# Error While calling a function in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, functional-programming, pyspark

I created a simple function in PySpark which swaps the key,value pair and return it.

```
def swap(x):
    swapped = lambda x: (x[1],x[0])
    return swapped
```

I have an RDD which gives the count of words in a file:

```
wordsCount = wordsSplit.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: (a+b))
```

Now, when I call the function to swap key,value pairs, it throws an error:

```
wordsCountSwap = wordsCount.map(swap)
wordsCountSwap.collect()
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumit/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/home/sumit/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/sumit/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 272, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/home/sumit/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 447, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Can anyone help me out?

P.S.: I'm able to perform the same task by using a simple lambda expression!

```
swap = lambda x : (x[1],x[0])
wordsCountSwap = wordsCount.map(swap)
wordsCountSwap.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `swap` function, you didn't call the `swapped` lambda function to return the swapped tuple but returned the lambda function itself.

A simple fix would be:

```py
def swap(x):
    swapped = lambda x: (x[1],x[0])
    return swapped(x)
#                 ^^^
```

Comment: I mixed the concept of a normal function and function with lambda expression. My bad!!

Answer (score 2):

> PS: I'm able to perform the same task using simple lambda expression!

And that is a perfectly valid way to do what you want.

```
rdd.map(lambda x : (x[1], x[0])).collect()
```

The `def` approach is simply replacing `lambda` with `def`, and adding a return, not adding *another* function in between.

```
def swap(x):
  return x[1], x[0]

rdd.map(swap).collect()
```

To see it more visually, take the Scala approach

```
rdd.map(_ => swap(_))
```

Becomes

```
rdd.map(swap)
```

Where the map argument (a single RDD record) is passed implicitly to the function, which only accepts one parameter